# Как поместить bootstrap popover у другого элемента?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Как сделать так, чтобы при фокусе на `input` *popover* отображался не возле самого `input`-а, а возле иконки со знаком вопроса (`id="q1"`)?

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label>Дата начала страхования: <i id="q1" class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></label>           
<input name="date_start" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ДД.ММ.ГГГГ" rel="popover" data-container="body" data-content="Укажите дату, с которой действует ваш страховой полис"  data-trigger="focus">      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переносим все необходимые `data-` в элемент `q1`

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Дата начала страхования: <i id="q1" class="fa fa-question-circle" rel="popover" data-container="body" data-content="Укажите дату, с которой действует ваш страховой полис" data-toggle="popover"></i></label>           
<input name="date_start" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ДД.ММ.ГГГГ">      
</div>
```

и добавляем немного JS код на показ popoverа

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[name=date_start]').bind('focus',function() {
        $('#q1').popover('show');
    });
});
</script>
```